# Remove labels from imported file in R

Tags: r

I am importing a file and trying to display only the numbers in each row, with any commas or labels. With the following code, my output is given below:

```
mydata <- read.table("/home/mukhera3/Desktop/Test/part-r-00000", sep=",")
mydata
```

Output

```
1       0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
     V461 V462 V463 V464 V465 V466 V467 V468 V469 V470 V471 V472 V473 V474 V475 V476 V477 V478 V479 V480 V481 V482 V483
1       0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
     V484 V485 V486 V487 V488 V489 V490 V491 V492 V493 V494 V495 V496 V497 V498 V499 V500 V501 V502 V503 V504 V505 V506
1       0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
     V507 V508 V509 V510 V511 V512 V513 V514 V515 V516 V517 V518 V519 V520 V521 V522 V523 V524 V525 V526 V527 V528 V529
1       0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
     V530 V531 V532 V533 V534 V535 V536 V537 V538 V539 V540 V541 V542 V543 V544 V545 V546 V547 V548 V549 V550 V551 V552
1       0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
     V553 V554 V555 V556 V557 V558 V559 V560 V561 V562 V563 V564 V565 V566 V567 V568 V569 V570 V571 V572 V573 V574 V575
```

When I replace the "," for sep with whitespace (sep=""), keeping everything else the same. this is what I get:

```
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
```

I want to display the numbers 0,1 .. without any commas or other row numbers etc. I am new to R programming, and do not know how to do this. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want your file to be read directly as a vector and not as a dataframe, you can, for instance, use `scan` instead of `read.table`. Example with your example file saved as `a.txt` in my working directory:

```
> mydata <- scan(file="a.txt",sep=",")
Read 46 items
> mydata
 [1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

You can also get that result from `read.table` with some additional steps:

```
> mydata <- read.table("a.txt",sep=",") # Reads your file as a data.frame
> mydata <- unlist(mydata) # Transforms into a named vector
> names(mydata) <- NULL # Gets rid of the names
> mydata
 [1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

If you just want to "display" it like that but don't want to change the nature of your table, you can simply use `cat` (combined with `unlist`):

```
> mydata <- read.table("a.txt",sep=",")
> cat(unlist(mydata))
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Comment: that almost worked..but I cannot have the row number, I just need the array of numbers

Comment: You don't have any row number here. The `[1]` is just the way R GUI displays `print` statements on vectors. (When you type `mydata` only, it is implicitely a command `print(mydata)`). If you want to display your data without that, use `cat` (`cat(mydata)` in the first example). `cat` prints directly to stdout so there is no extra things like indices, row numbers, etc. printed.

Comment: thank you so much, the one with cat worked perfectly!!